Custom constructor for a Rank 2 matrix in Julia
I have built a custom constructor for a Rank 2 matrix, which stores 2 custom Rank 1 matrices. The custom constructors for the Rank 1 matrices store 2 vectors.
begin
    struct RankOneMatrix{T} <: AbstractMatrix{T}
        v::AbstractVector{T}
        w::AbstractVector{T}
    end

    RankOneMatrix(v) = RankOneMatrix(v, v)
end

begin

    struct RankTwoMatrix{T} <: AbstractMatrix{T}
        # Your code here
        A::RankOneMatrix{T}
        B::RankOneMatrix{T}
    end

    RankTwoMatrix(v1, v2) = RankTwoMatrix(RankOneMatrix(v1), 
    RankOneMatrix(v2))
end

begin
   x = 1.0:5.0
   y = 0.5:0.5:3.0
   rank_2 = RankTwoMatrix(RankOneMatrix(collect(x)), 
   RankOneMatrix(collect(y)))
end

When I initialize an instance for RankTwoMatrix, I am thrown an error:
Failed to show value:

MethodError: no method matching iterate(::Missing)

Closest candidates are:

iterate(!Matched::Base.RegexMatchIterator)

@ Base regex.jl:686

iterate(!Matched::Base.RegexMatchIterator, !Matched::Any)

@ Base regex.jl:686

iterate(!Matched::BitSet)

@ Base bitset.jl:326

I suppoose I am making a mistake in initialising RankTwoMatrix. Also, according to the documentation, there is no need for us to define a method "iterate" as displayed in the error. What is going on?

This is the same "Failed to show value" issue that was discussed already in a very recent question from a user with an extremely similar name to yours. Have you read the answer there, and does it answer your question here?

You've defined your type, which is a subtype of AbstractMatrix, but you haven't defined how to index into your type or iterate its values or do anything else with it. The default show method for abstract matrices iterates the values in the matrix and shows them, hence the error. Check out the interface guide for implementing arrays:
https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/interfaces/#man-interface-array

Thanks for the answer! The documentation states that it is an optional method; what does that mean then?

Any method is only required if the code you happen to run requires it. Do the things you want to do with the type and see what method errors get thrown. When you don't get any more method errors, you've implemented enough of the itnerface for your use case.
